# VBA don’t overwrite cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that matches data from a master workbook to another and if it matches it pulls other column rows to the “Master” sheet. Only issue I have is that it’s overwriting the other filled columns. It’s not just pasting over to the matched cells, what can I do to stop this? Added a single part of the code

If Valuetocheck = valueinnew Then

```
mastersheet.Cells(A, 3).Value = workbooktocheck.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(b, 7)
mastersheet.Cells(A, 11).Value = workbooktocheck.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(b, 11)
```

Comment: What is `A` and `b` in your *`RowReference`* for the `Cells()` property? Can you also elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do - edit your question to include a [mcve] and perhaps some sample data (Doesn't need to be real data, just something to demonstrate what you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

I would need to Know what A refers to in the code.
Are they fixed or are they variables that can change? If they vary then all the columns that A assumes will be overwritten.

Alternatively you could use:

```
If mastersheet.Cells(A, 3).Value = "" then
    mastersheet.Cells(A, 3).Value = workbooktocheck.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(b, 7)
end if
If mastersheet.Cells(A, 11).Value = "" then
     mastersheet.Cells(A, 11).Valueworkbooktocheck.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(b, 11)
End If
```

To prevent the cell being overwritten if it's already filled.

Comment: Hello thanks for this, yes they are variables. I already have an If statement " If Valuetocheck = valueinnew Then" just above my code....will this still work?

Comment: I'm not sure how that condition relates to the cells that are being copied and written, but I guess that that's what's causing your current problem - that condition is true and so it overwrites. What I know for sure is that if you put an If before every writing operation it won't overwrite anything, it will just write if the cell is blank.